# Mulesoft connector for SFDC and custom restresource

Tags: connected-apps, mulesoft

can you confirm that Mule connector for SFDC allows "only" to perform common actions (read, update, delete, create) on standard SFDC objects (such as Account, Contact, ....)?
Consider, for example, below method created as RestResource on SFDC

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/customOrder')
global with sharing class CustomOrder {


    @HttpPost
    global static Account createOrder() {
      RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
      RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
      Map<String, Object> params = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(req.requestBody.toString());
      ----
      ---
      Account resultAcc;
      ---
      return resultAcc
    }
  }
```

how can i query it with Mulesoft SFDC connector? I've tried to use "Invoke Apex class", but my class isn't shown in the Mule connector.

Comment: Per MuleSoft's documentation, "Invoke Apex Class" only works with Apex Web Services exposed as SOAP services. In your case, the one above is a REST service. That may be the case why you are not able to view it in your connector. Excerpt from [**documentation**](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/salesforce-connector) -- **For now, only Apex methods exposed as SOAP services can be invoked.**

Comment: I'm using Mulesoft 3.9 and i think it is supported, look at here --> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/salesforce-connector

Comment: My bad, I must have been looking at another version’s documentation.